# Cómo cambiar atributo de TailwindCss con useState en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind

Hace no demasiado he empezado a programar y estoy aprendiendo React recientemente.

Estoy intentando hacer un carousel de imágenes con dicha librería; al pulsar flecha de avance, muestre la imagen siguiente y al pulsar flecha de retroceso muestre la imagen anterior.

Se me ha ocurrido usar useState para cambiar el estado del css (estoy usando Tailwind) modificando el atributo `translate-x-[Xrem]` donde `X` es el valor de la variable move.

El caso es que a pesar de que me cambia el valor de la variable de `useState`, no me renderiza el resultado.

Dejo el código a continuación a ver si pudieran ayudarme.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

```javascript
const Carouselfinal = () => {
  const [move, setMove] = useState(-11);
  return (
        <div className='flex justify-center items-center '>
            <div className=''>
                <IoIosArrowBack size={40} className='cursor-pointer' onClick={()=>setMove(move-11)}/>
            </div>
            <div className='my-20 w-[calc((10+4)*4rem)] h-36 px-4 overflow-hidden'>
                <div className={`carousel flex items-center gap-4 w-fit h-[100%] ease-in-out duration-300 translate-x-[${move}rem] `}>
                    <img src={aventon} alt="" className='w-[10rem]'/>
                    <img src={burga} alt="" className='w-[10rem]'/>
                    <img src={catholic} alt="" className='w-[10rem]'/>
                    <img src={client1} alt="" className='w-[10rem]'/>
                    <img src={client3} alt="" className='w-[10rem]'/>
                    <img src={client4} alt="" className='w-[10rem]'/>
                    <img src={client5} alt="" className='w-[10rem]'/>
                    <img src={client6} alt="" className='w-[10rem]'/>
                    <img src={fittrack} alt="" className='w-[10rem]'/>
                    <img src={harper} alt="" className='w-[10rem]'/>
                    <img src={hdsuply} alt="" className='w-[10rem]'/>
                    <img src={nbcgolf} alt="" className='w-[10rem]'/>
                    <img src={snow} alt="" className='w-[10rem]'/>
                </div>   
            </div>
            <div>
                <IoIosArrowForward size={40} className='cursor-pointer' onClick={()=>setMove(move-11)} />
            </div>
        </div>
  )
}

export default Carouselfinal
```